One confusion in Riesz interpolation in Functional analysis by Stein-Shakarchi
It is in the proof of the Riesz interpolation theorem in Chapter 2 section 2, page 56. I formulate it as follows.
If $f\in L^p(X)$, write $f^U= f \chi_E$ and $f^L=f-f^U$, where $E=\{x\in X: |f(x)|\geq 1\}$.
Now for $1\leq p_0<p<p_1$. We easily deduce that $f^U \in L^{p_0}, f^L\in L^{p_1}$.
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $f_n\to f$ in the $L^p$-norm. The authors then deduce that $f^U_n \to f^U$ in $L^{p_0}$-norm. I can not understand this step. Can you give me some hints. Thanks.

$E$ has finite measure, so it is enough to show that $f^U_n \to f^U$ in $L^{p}$-norm.

@geetha290krm Thanks. Yes. but how to show this. If we assume these simple functions satisfy $|f_n|\leq |f_{n+1}|$, then we can show this easily. But I can not figour out the general case....
